# Preserving column data types in Hadoop UDF output (Streaming)

Tags: python, hadoop, hive, apache-pig, hadoop-streaming

I'm writing a UDF in Python for a Hive query on Hadoop. My table has several `bigint` fields, and several `string` fields.

My UDF modifies the `bigint` fields, subtracts the modified versions into a new column (should also be numeric), and leaves the `string` fields as is.

**When I run my UDF in a query, the results are all `string` columns.**

**How can I preserve or specify types in my UDF output?**

---

*More details:*

My Python UDF:

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    # pre-process row
    line = line.strip()
    inputs = line.split('\t')

    # modify numeric fields, calculate new field
    inputs[0], inputs[1], new_field = process(int(inputs[0]), int(inputs[1]))

    # leave rest of inputs as is; they are string fields.

    # output row
    outputs = [new_field]
    outputs.extend(inputs)
    print '\t'.join([str(i) for i in outputs]) # doesn't preserve types!
```

I saved this UDF as `myudf.py` and added it to Hive.

My Hive query:

```
CREATE TABLE calculated_tbl AS
SELECT TRANSFORM(bigintfield1, bigintfield2, stringfield1, stringfield2)
USING 'python myudf.py'
AS (calculated_int, modified_bif1, modified_bif2, stringfield1, stringfield2)
FROM original_tbl;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Streaming sends everything through stdout. It is really just a wrapper on top of hadoop streaming under the hood. All types get converted to strings, which you handled accordingly in your python udf,  and come back into hive as a strings. A python transform in hive will never return anything but strings. You could try to do a the transform in a sub query, and then cast the results to a type:

```
 SELECT cast(calculated_int as bigint)
        ,cast( modified_bif1 as bigint)
        ,cast( modified_bif2 as bigint) 
        ,stringfield1 
        ,stringfield2
 FROM ( 
 SELECT TRANSFORM(bigintfield1, bigintfield2, stringfield1, stringfield2)
 USING 'python myudf.py'
 AS (calculated_int, modified_bif1, modified_bif2, stringfield1, stringfield2)
 FROM original_tbl) A ;
```

Hive might let you get away with this, if it does not, You will need to save the results to a table, and then you can convert (cast) to a different type in another query.

The final option it to just use a Java UDF. Map only UDFs are not too bad, and they allow you to specify return types.

**Update** (from asker):

The above answer works really well. A more elegant solution I found reading the "Programming Hive" O'Reilly book a few weeks later is this:

```
CREATE TABLE calculated_tbl AS
SELECT TRANSFORM(bigintfield1, bigintfield2, stringfield1, stringfield2)
USING 'python myudf.py'
AS (calculated_int BIGINT, modified_bif1 BIGINT, modified_bif2 BIGINT, stringfield1 STRING, stringfield2 STRING)
FROM original_tbl;
```

Rather than casting, you can specify types right in the `AS(...)` line.